# how can i scale all these petals together?

Tags: transforms

i am trying to model a windmill and have this:

[image]

No i want my selections so scale like this:

[image]

if i now use transform normal with individual origins, it scales like this:

[image]

how do i scale this right?

Comment: easiest way would be select one loop, S to scale, Shift + Y to exclude other axis... immediately select other loop, Shift + R to repeat, select the other and Shift + R... if you select only front and back segments, set transform orientations to normal and pivot point to individual origins it should work with just scaling, but so many steps... if you had faces I would select outer ones and Alt + S to scale along normals... guess there are other ways

Comment: or just edit a single mesh and have array modifier or a couple of clones...

Comment: @alambre: that's what i did at the end ;) But i was curious how or if you could model this

Comment: @alambre: you won't believe it - S - Shift -Y worked for all 3 if all are selected too. So although you didn't know ;) you brought me on the right way. If you want, write it as answer  - i will accept it! I did just try S Y Y and same with x instead Shift Y ...great! Thank you!!

Comment: I managed to scale all three together with Shift-X instead of Shift-Y, but only if I selected the top and bottom edges... not the complete edge loops. Then it all gets messy. The same with Robin's answer, it only worked partially for me. Don't know why it behaves so differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as the elements you are transforming are disconnected islands, you can set the Transform Pivot to 'Individual Origins'. The normals of the individual edge-loops are as they would be, if the loops were faces.

In my case, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> in the 'Normal' orientation does the job. It may be <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> for you.

[image]

On the whole, though, would it be better to model this item under a rotational *Array* modifier? Just in case there are other modifications you want to make to all three blades that can't be executed so conveniently this way.

Comment: That's exactly how I would have scaled it (apart from that I would rather use an _Array_ modifier as you also suggested), but the strange thing is, two of three scale correctly (in your image the top and right one), the third (bottom one) didn't - it showed a green line as it's Y axis along which it scaled that was parallel to the X axis. And that's how it worked when one wing is oriented parallel to the X axis. If the mesh is rotated so that no wing is parallel to X or Y axis, then the scaling gets completely messed up.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ahh.. good point? I'll try it when I can. That sounds like an undefined axis (division by 0 being covered with a default)?

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is scaling along normals (Alt+S), but it will scale all outwards...
You could do it and then scale back the y axis.

Comment: if i have to scale everything manually...i could directly scale manually. I don't see any improvement in your answer....

Comment: @Chris Not the best solution. But it's not scaling all manually. You could use Alt+S, then S > Y and hold Ctrl to snap to the vertices that have the correct Y position.